# Integrate figma file to angular material

Tags: angular-material, figma

I have some file generated from figma. A plugin has been used for material design.

I have a folder css

```
colors.module.css
theme.dark.css
theme.ligh.css
tokens.css
typography.module.css
```

I don't have any information about how to integrate that with angular material